# Add event when slide changes in carousel.js / Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm using Bootstrap 3.2 and its own Carousel.js to display sliding images.

On every slide I would like to display differents divs that are in another part of my page.

So I've checked the documentation to attach an action when every single slide is set to active. Looking at the documentation I though to find a solution with this:

```
slid.bs.carousel    This event is fired when the carousel has completed its slide transition.
```

But it doesn't work and probably it is not the correct way to use that event type. I can assume this because I've put an alert in `$('#carousel-example-generic').on('slide.bs.carousel'[...]` and it never shows up. (Obviously I've included jQuery library)

So, as I said before I would like to attach an action when image is set to active and restart event on every slide. Which method should I have to use? Any suggestion?

Comment: This is correct, you should and can use that event to react on each slide change.  You can then interrogate via selectors to find the currently `active` slide and show you alternative content accordingly.  Perhaps adding something like a `data` attribute to each slide you can store the `id` of the additional content and show when needed.  Please can you provide a demo on bootply.com or jsfiddle.net of where you are encountering issues of the event not firing?

Comment: @RobSchmuecker here's my code for slider: http://www.bootply.com/pw5C0mpcax in bootply it goes into and shows alert, but not in my page. Here's the code of my page: http://pastebin.com/QSFfMRGL

Comment: Have a look at this, it's not perfect but it gives you the gist of what you need to do.  As I mentioned you can use your own identifiers where needed and own animations or whatever. http://www.bootply.com/bRrkSwkYE2